# Can I use both onload and onclick events in one anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, events

I had a requirement of loading data from database when I click one jsp link and at the time of loading only it should retrieve data from database

Here is my code but it is not working

`<td><a href="#" onclick="return popitup('jsp/menu/Equipment/Equipment11.jsp')" onload=document.form.submit()><s:label name="Equipment" value="Equipment" /></a></td>`

In my main screen that Equipment box will be there and when I click that it should open new window and at time of opening itself it should fire a request to action class and should retrieve data from db and display that data in that equipment screen.

Comment: afaik onload event is only valid on body/frame elements, not on links, so your onload event should be attached to the html body returned by jsp/menu/Equipment/Equipment11.jsp and trigger the submit method of the form by using window.opener.document.forms['form_name'].submit()

Answer (score 6):

You can have multiple events on one element. Anchor elements do not, however, have a load event in the first place.